# How to use CXF instead of Metro?

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf, java-metro-framework

How to use Apache CXF instead of Metro (it's JDK 6) in a Maven project? What dependencies do I need to use and what file to create in `META-INF/services`? I can't find this information in CXF site...

ps. It's a JAX-WS client, not a server. Only client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Maven, you likely just need to depend on cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws.   That's it.  It will pull the rest of the stuff in transitively. It contains the META-INF/services file so you don't need to do anything.   It really should be that simple.